# How to fetch payment details for an Order via realex payment api

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, payment-gateway, realex-payments-api

I want to know whether there is any API though which I can check if the payment for a particular order is captured or not at Realex Payment End. Requirement is that if payment is captured at realex end but not in our system than we fetch the payment details and save in our DB also for reconciliation purposes.

I need an example for Java.